# Как оставить нижнюю панель задач?

Tags: видео

Есть ли возможность смотреть на винде развёрнутые видео и одновременно видеть нижнюю панель инструментов windows?

Comment: Могу лайфхак подсказать, просто растяните окно до панели задач 

Comment: Я так и знал, что это совет появится. Но он не работает. Видимо я не корректно написал вопрос. Но на большее мне литературного таланта не хватает.

Comment: В самом приложении (видеоплеере) должна быть реализована эта фича.